Unable to prevent and identify DDoss attack Originating from our Server's
we are using hetzner dedicated server.
we have a public server ( Ngnix reverse proxy server) then it have around 10 upstream server's.
someone just got in our web server via some application vulnerability and doing Ddos to some other Ip's,first we got the email that our servers are being used for Ddos attack then we look in that.
and setup everything to identify Ddoss attack but unable to identify the root cause unable to prevent it from happening,
This is what we have done till now,
-Setup Zabbix for infrastructure monitoring more specifically we are monitoring out going packet's.
-Enable the firewalls between upstream server's.
-Setup ELK for logs of nginx reverse proxy because every outgoing is incoming going through nginx reverse proxy. but didn't find any thing suspicious
-Block every outgoing and incoming traffic from our firewall (Mikrotic).only these are enable ssh-22,DNS-53,HTTP-80,HTTPS-443 are now enable and some other application ports.
we are enable to prevent ddos attack even after that precaution's.
any suggestion would be appreciated
our main goal is too prevent that from happening and how we can identify files related to Ddos attack.
